# default='False' is not reflected in django admin BooleanField when adding a new item

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, field

1) When I add new item in django admin site, all checkboxes are set to true, even if default is set to false.

2) If I don't touch any of them and save the item, when I reopen it to editing, all checkboxes are set to their apropriate values according the default (some true, some false).

3) If I uncheck and recheck some which should be false by default, it doesn't have any effect after reopening (it's false, like i didn't touch it).

4) If I uncheck some which should be true, it's value is saved (so it's false later)

5) When I later edit the values they ARE saved exactly as expected. no glitches.

Did you ever encounter similar glitches? Where was the problem?

(on django 1.3.1, python 2.6.6, sqlite3)

```
Something1 = models.BooleanField(default='False')
Something2 = models.BooleanField(default='True')
Something3 = models.BooleanField(default='False')
```

thanks

Comment: [`True` and `False`](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#False) are built in constants not strings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should pass a boolean value, not a string. In your case:

```
Something1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
Something2 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
Something3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 7):

For a `BooleanField` Django is expecting a boolean value, not a string! Strings will be evaluated to the boolean value of `True` which you can easily verify in the python console:

```
>>> bool('True')
True
>>> bool('False')
True
```

So you have to use something like `Something1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)`.